# ERROR : Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafk a$)

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm running first time Kafka on my windows 7 and getting error starting the Kafka-Service

1. I downloaded kafka_2.12-2.0.0 and unzipped on C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0
2. In C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties changed
   dataDir
   to
   dataDir=C:/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/data/zookeeper
   (folder dataDir=C:/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/data/zookeeper created)
3. In C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\config\server.properties changed
   log.dirs
   to
   log.dirs=C:/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/data/kafka
   (folder C:/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/data/kafka created)
4. Run from cmd with admin permission zookeeper server

   \bin\windowszookeeper-server-start.bat
   C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties
   it's running on port 2181 (getting INFO binding to port
   0.0.0./0.0.0.0:2181)
5. Run from another cmd with admin permission kafka server

   \bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat
   C:\kafka_2.12- 2.0.0\config\server.properties

I'm getting error : ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafk
a$)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\kafka_2.12- (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)

Comment: Error : at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:536)
        at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:42)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the configuration file location when you start kafka:

> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

Also check the getting started page of kafka to check the basic steps to follow in order to validate the installation:

[Get started with kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

Comment: Hello, I'm running from bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.12- 2.0.0\config\server.properties

Comment: @Rudi there seems to be a space in your path to config file after "2.12-". Try removing the space.

Comment: thanks for recommendation  . I able to run it after download last version . but I run second time and  get error  : "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap"

Comment: @Rudi: this is due to a big heap size that kafka allocates by default. you can reduce the default min/max heap sizes used by kafka by setting this environment variable  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms1G"

Comment: thank you for recommendation,its help, currently getting error log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\Users\rg65481\kafka_2.12-2.2.0/logs/controller.
log] to [C:\Users\rg65481\kafka_2.12-2.2.0/logs/controller.log.2019-04-10-09].
[2019-04-10 10:16:59,518]

Comment: That's strange. Do you have 2 kafka instance running? Also make sure that you started the program in admin mode because you did so at the beginning according to your post. Also try restart everything

Comment: after restart continue to work  its solve problem,now, trying to "kafka-console-consumer" after produce messages and gettin error :  Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient).

Comment: Try to follow exactly the documentation. The consumer should be working fine if kafka is started

Comment: Its work !I able to solve this issue after I reinstall JVM 64bit. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Great! Cheers! :-)